# CSS Siblings, First

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

We are using a bought packaged theme with the following CSS:

```
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled + label  {
     color: #999;
 }
 <div class=rdio> 
    <input type=checkbox>
     <label....>
 <div>
```

As you can see it only is applied if a label is directly a sibling of the checkbox.

**We can't alter the CSS**, I have to write a **Custom.css** to be loaded after the main theme css.

what new, additional CSS can I add that would allow for this (first label sibling, but not direct)

```
 <div class=rdio> 
   <input type=checkbox>
   <one element of anything>
   <label....>
</div>
```

I'm looking for the overide I can do, as I can't edit the original css.

Comment: have you tried nth-child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two options, the obvious:

```
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled + * + label
```

And the (marginally) less obvious use of the general sibling combinator (the `~`):

```
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ label
```

If you really must only target, as your question implies, the *first* `label` element following the `input`:

```
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ label {
    /* style the labels */
}

.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ label ~ label {
    /* override subsequent label element styling */
}
```